# how to use redirect(url_for('index')) with id to reload the index.html with specific section

Tags: flask

My index.html file contains Links to a location/sections on the same page; one of which is 'content'.
After sending email when I am using below line in my .py -
return redirect(url_for('index'))

I wanted to reopen my index.html with section which id=content
I tried - url_for('index',id="content") but not working.

Which way should I modify my redirect(url_for.... line to achieve this?
Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass your `id` as `_anchor`:

```
url_for('index', _anchor="content")
```

See [`url_for`'s docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) for more information.