# Redirecting to the central part of a webapp

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, flask

In the website I am creating, I want to include a form that gets the information contained in the button the user presses and then sends information through flask. Then with render_templates it comes back to the same tab. 
The button that the user clicks is not a nav-button but a submit one. 
How can I add a bookmark so that the user goes back to the middle of the page and not the top every time he presses this button to send the form?

In my case, I am using flask. I use the following code:

```
@app.route("/me")
def me():
    return render_template("me.html",objeto=objeto)
```

I want to go to the middle part of "me.html" but I cannot add "me.html#middle_part" as a bookmark here...

So I cannot create a conventional bookmark... Any ideas?

What @Don Smythe explained helped me, but what if the button is not a navigation tab but a form? Then there is no "href" attribute where you can put the url_for function... Any help? I am referring to this question:

Link to a specific location in a Flask template

Answer (score 0):

You can add an specific id to an element in your destination page, then just add `#tagId` to the end of your link. for example put this id in target page:

```
 <div id="tagId">...</div>
```

And your link must be like this

```
<a href="/somewhere#tagId">Link</a>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! But my problem is that that the link is used with flask (library of python, do not know if you have used it before). The function render_templates will show the tab "me" going to me.html file.

(See the code on the edit question)

Maybe I can create a bookmark but that it doesnt have to be clicked? Dont know how to do it...

Comment: I hope it help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483125/how-to-use-redirecturl-forindex-with-id-to-reload-the-index-html-with-spec?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
@MTT

Comment: Thank you! But I am not using links... So that is why this doesnt help me